# How can I get Property Expression for field of a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I'm using Entity Framework 6.  I have 2 classes:

```
public class BookingRecord
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CustomerId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer {get; set;}

    ......
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int BusinessUnitId {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}

    ......
}
```

And I have BusinessUnitId on User as the Business Unit.

My business logic is:

> If User is Administrator, the user can open all booking records in the system.
>   If User is Employee, the user can open all booking records with the same BusinessUnitId on User.
>   If User is RegisteredUser, the user can only open booking records with the same UserId with the user.
>   If User is other roles, the user cannot open booking record at all.

So I have created an Expression for Customer Class for the business logic above.

```
    protected Expression GetUserRoleExtraConditionExpression(ParameterExpression param)
    {
        Expression expression;

        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;

        if (user.IsInRole(Consts.Roles.Administrator))
        {
            expression = Expression.Constant(true);
        }
        else if (user.IsInRole(Consts.Roles.Employee))
        {
            int businessUnitId = UserManager.FindById(user.Identity.GetUserId()).BusinessUnitId;
            expression = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("BusinessUnitId")),
                Expression.Constant(businessUnitId));
        }
        else if (user.IsInRole(Consts.Roles.RegisteredUser))
        {
            string userId = user.Identity.GetUserId();
            expression = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("UserId")),
                Expression.Constant(userId));
        }
        else
        {
            expression = Expression.Constant(false);
        }
        return expression;
    }
```

In which ParameterExpression param is a param of type Customer.

For BookingRecord class, I need the same logic to be applied on the Customer property.  I.e., `BookingRecord.Customer.BusinessUnitId` and `BookingRecord.Customer.UserId` must apply the above Expression when it is selected from DB.

How can I re-use the method on BookingRecord?

In other word, how can I get an Expression similar like `Expression.Property(param, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("BusinessUnitId"))` but accepts param with the type of BookingRecord and applies on the field of the CustomerField of BookingRecord?
Something like

```
Expression.Property(param,
    typeof(BookingRecord)
        .GetProperty(Customer)
        .GetProperty("BusinessUnitId"))
```

Comment: Why are you going to such great lengths to generate an expression here?

Comment: `Expression.Property(Expression.Property(param,...),...)`

Comment: Thanks pinkfloydx33, I soon found out it's just this easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks pinkfloydx33.
`Expression.Property(Expression.Property(param,...),...)` is just what I was looking for.

So I have the method now as

```
    protected Expression GetUserRoleExtraConditionExpression(Expression param)
    {
        Expression expression;

        IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;

        if (user.IsInRole(Consts.Roles.Administrator))
        {
            expression = Expression.Constant(true);
        }
        else if (user.IsInRole(Consts.Roles.Employee))
        {
            int businessUnitId = UserManager.FindById(user.Identity.GetUserId()).BusinessUnitId;
            expression = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "BusinessUnitId"),
                Expression.Constant(businessUnitId));
        }
        else if (user.IsInRole(Consts.Roles.RegisteredUser))
        {
            string userId = user.Identity.GetUserId();
            expression = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "UserId"),
                Expression.Constant(userId));
        }
        else
        {
            expression = Expression.Constant(false);
        }
        return expression;
    }
```

And in caller of Customer class I call it as

`GetUserRoleExtraConditionExpression(param);`

(`param` is `Customer` type `ParameterExpression`)

and in caller of BookingRecord class I call it as

`GetUserRoleExtraConditionExpression(Expression.Property(param, "Customer"))`

(`param` is a `BookingRecord` type `ParameterExpression`)